Can Apple Silicon GPU / MPS profiles be viewed in Chrome or other profile viewer (not XCode)?
I am trying to view MPS in software that is not XCode for which an Apple account is needed.
Most other hardware (CPU, XPU, NVIDIA GPUs, etc.) allow easy profiling in torch.

Can the profiles generated by torch.mps.profiling  be viewed with software other than XCode maybe chrome or safari profiler?
Or even printed to a file and viewed by naked eye, like other activity profiles?

I've currently tried to run the profiler, but since it's unclear where is the mps profile stored (no path can be specified.) and likely is a binary, private format, it's unclear how one could do it.
I am aware of this PyTorch Issue, but I'm talking about the torch.mps.profiling which does record.
